# Another Triple Boot Classic Mac Pro Project

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, grub

Forgive me for asking a question that has been asked a number of times over the last many years. In my case after several weeks of searching and researching, I have not found an answer that is current enough regarding both my equipment, software patching programs and boot-loaders. I am a bit reluctant to proceed with any one guide as the process has and continues to change as different software patches and improved boot-loaders are always in play.

I am looking for a guide to make my 2012 Mac Pro 5,1 triple boot MacOS Big Sur (eventually Ventura), Windows 10 (eventually Windows 11) and Ubuntu 23.04 (and keeping Ubuntu up-to-date with updates). I have been dual booting MacOS High Sierra and Windows 8.1 for a number of years. I recently updated my Mac Pro with a metal supported GPU (Nvidia 860 flashed for Mac Pro), the latest firmware (144.0.0.0.0), latest wireless (802.11ac and BT4.0), 64GB memory and a 2TB Samsung SDD. Lately I have been running an OpenCore Legacy Patcher install of MacOS Big Sur and the system has been running flawlessly. I still need Windows and I really liked the triple booting Hackintosh I built several years ago (that was doomed by Apple’s release of Yosemite - my Grub installation corrupted and in trying to get things to play nice with each other eventually bricked the drive, causing a loss of some data).

With some of the excellent patching and installation apps out there, and wanting too keep my classic Mac Pro relevant for at least 2-3 more years, I once again would like to operate a three OS platform. My question is how best to achieve this end. I planned on keeping Big Sur as the only OS on the SSD (and only the necessary partitions for loading from a GUI based boot-loader. I was going to put Windows 10 and Ubuntu 23.04 on an evenly partitioned 2TB HDD (although I could easily have Windows and Ubuntu installed on individual HDD’s).

But in what order (which OS to start with)? What installer patch should I use (OCLP, other installer/patch app)? What boot-loader (OCLP, rEFInd, etc.) to use and how do I partition for the EFI files, swap files, etc?

Any help from any of you would be greatly appreciated.

Jon

Comment: I am not a fan of multiple boot - I use Virtual Machines instead. But your 2012 machine will definitely not run Windows 11 production.

Comment: @John - I'm no big fan of triple boot, unless it's *one* Windows & as many macOS as you like. macOS itself has zero issues multiple-booting, it's adding nix that makes it difficult, because nix installers always want to take over the entire drive, so you have to barricade them behind rEFInd. I think once you get past the TPM requirement the 2012 Pro is more than fast enough to run Win 11 [it's faster than any other Mac built before 2019, the first time it was overtaken], though I've never tried it. The issue might be drivers, though Boot Camp itself provides drivers at least up to Win10.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Too much for a comment, if not really enough for a complete answer...</sup>

I have no experience with OCLP; my Pro is still on Mojave.
I've no real clue about the Ubuntu part or how to get it to play nice with rEFInd either, but I'd start off 'safe.
Three drives.
macOS on the first; use Boot Camp to get Win10 on it - if it will, the 5.1 isn't qualified for 10 by default, you usually have to start with Win7 & upgrade in-place. That you're already running Big Sur may change how Boot Camp sees the Mac, so you might be able to do it 'out of the box'. I can't test that.
Newer versions of macOS & Windows no longer need the protected MBR structure, so they're easier to move around without things breaking.

Once you've got that, move it to drive 2 [maybe still needs WinClone, not sure at Big Sur] & reclaim your space on both drives.

Now you're free to play with nix & rEFInd on drive 3, with less of a chance of the install killing the others by accident.

BTW, I wouldn't run any OS off spinny rust these days. It will be slower than running from a VM. 1TB SSDs are under $£€ 100 now, smaller ones come free in cornflakes packets ;) Spinny rust is for Time Machine & long-term storage, nothing else, & you can get 6 SATA drives in that Mac before you even need a PCI riser. 3GB/s is fast enough most of the time, PCI risers & NVMe if you need faster. [Note PCI + SATA III is not noticeably faster in real-world than SATA II]. Also note the Mac thinks any drive on a PCI riser is external; which in itself causes no issues but feels a bit odd.

To get Win 11 on there using Boot Camp you need a registry hack - this has a guide [untested] - https://machow2.com/windows-11-mac-boot-camp/ I'm not sure how this works if you upgrade in place from Win10. I still just have Win10 on mine in Boot Camp, which I rarely use these days, everything else is in VM. I have VMs of Win XP, 7, 10 & every Mac OS from Snow Leo to Monterey ;))